# Hadoop spiled records

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I couldn't find any documentation on how hadoop handles splilled records. Is there a link that can be found online.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Map+Parameters and the section right below it http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#Shuffle%2FReduce+Parameters

I'm not sure if this covers what you're looking for, but hopefully it points you in a direction to start looking some more.